# How to trigger specific Execute pipeline activity?

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a main pipeline in Azure Synapse. This main pipeline only contains several "Execute pipeline" activities.

I want to trigger automatically 2 of these activities and not the other.

I tried "If condition" with boolean : if true trigger automatically the execute pipeline that has true parameter, but nothing happened.

What is the way to do it ?

Comment: based on which condition you are triggering the activities?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to trigger automatically 2 of these activities and not the other

You cannot automatically trigger any activity in ADF or synapse pipeline. You need to use if activity or switch activity here as per your requirement like below.

Give your Boolean condition in the if activity expression.

[image]

Inside the **True activities of if activity**, give your execute pipeline activities.

[image]

You can keep these in serial or in parallel as per your requirement.

Put the remaining execute pipeline activities in the **False activities of if activity** so that they won't execute when your Boolean value is true.

You can use [**Switch activity**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-switch-activity) as well but you need to change the switch activity expression as per your requirement.